# Converting row into column in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports

My crystal report data source has rows like

```
|---------+--------+----------+----------|
| SubName | TMarks | ObtMarks | ExamType |
|---------+--------+----------+----------|
|  ABC    |  100   |    70    |   1st    |
|---------+--------+----------+----------|
|  DEF    |  100   |    70    |   1st    |
|---------+--------+----------+----------|
|  ABC    |  100   |    90    |   2nd    |
|---------+--------+----------+----------|
|  DEF    |  100   |    80    |   2nd    |
|---------+--------+----------+----------|
```

I want to show this on crystal report like

```
|---------+--------+-----------+-----------|
| SubName | TMarks | ObtMarks1 | ObtMarks2 |    
|---------+--------+-----------+-----------|
|  ABC    |  100   |    70     |    90     |
|---------+--------+-----------+-----------|
|  DEF    |  100   |    70     |    80     |
|---------+--------+-----------+-----------|
```

How can I group the record so that I may get the desired result? I want the ExamType = "2nd" to be displayed on the next column but with the corresponding SubName. I tried with group by ExamType but it is showing the 2nd group below the 1st.

Can anybody help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you only want to show the ExamType=2, then how will you show the result of ObtMarks1??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

group by `SubName`

1. Create a formula `ObtMarks  1` write below code:

   ```
   if ExamType ="1st"
   then ObtMarks
   ```
2. Create another formula `ObtMarks 2` write below code:

   ```
   if ExamType ="2nd"
   then ObtMarks
   ```

Now place these columns in `Group Footer` side by side

Comment: thanks a lot. You have solved the problem I was facing from 2 months. Thank you very very very much